# Memory issue when download and store a lot of images in background

Tags: ios, image, stored-procedures, memory-management, download

I don't like ask a question usually but this time a didn't find a solution for my problem so I have to ask to you how solve my problem.

I made a object **OffLineModeBrain** for download a lot of images in background while the app is working normal, I make the code, everything works well I have just a problem with the memory, I've tried in every solution to release it time by time but without result.
Basically in my  **OffLineModeBrain** I have a method for do that and load a progressive bar this is the code:

```
-(void)downloadAndSaveByArray:(NSArray *)array{


    //PATH
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSCachesDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *cachesImageFolderPath = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.hackemist.SDWebImageCache.default"];

    dispatch_queue_t queueImages = dispatch_queue_create("Images", NULL);
    dispatch_queue_t queueDownload = dispatch_queue_create("Download", NULL);
    //dispatch_queue_t queueStore = dispatch_queue_create("Store", NULL);

    int total = array.count;
    __block int progess = 0;
    __weak OffLineModeBrain *wself = self;
    dispatch_sync(queueImages, ^{
    for ( NSString *image in array) {
        if (_stop) {
            //
            NSLog(@"stop");
            _stop = NO;
            _downloading = NO;
            break;

        }else{
            //CHECK IMAGE IN LOCAL
            BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:
                            [cachesImageFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [[image MD5String] lowercaseString]]]];
            if (!success) {
                dispatch_sync(queueDownload, ^{
                    if (!_stop) {

                        //DOWNLOAD AND SAVE
                        NSError *error;
                        NSURL  *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:image];
                        _urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] ;
                        NSLog(@"Download");

                        if (_urlData)
                        {
                            //dispatch_sync(queueStore, ^{

                                NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", cachesImageFolderPath, [image MD5String]];
                                [_urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
                                NSLog(@"Stored");

                                //RETURN PROGRESS
                                progess = progess + 1;
                                [wself.delegate downloadImagesProgress:progess ofTotal:total];

                            //});


                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"Download Images erroe: %@", error);

                            //RETURN PROGRESS
                            progess = progess + 1;
                            [wself.delegate downloadImagesProgress:progess ofTotal:total];
                        }
                        //dsf
                    }else{
                        NSLog(@"stop");
                        progess = progess + 1;
                        if (progess == total) {
                            _stop = NO;

                        }
                        _downloading = NO;
                    }
                });


            }else{
                NSLog(@"Local");

                //RETURN PROGRESS
                progess = progess + 1;
                [wself.delegate downloadImagesProgress:progess ofTotal:total];
            }
        }

    }//FOR IMAGES ENDED
    });

}
```

this is  `downloadImagesProgress: ofTotal:` just a method for update the loading bar every time. the problem starts when i start to download the images one by one then them didm't release and still in the heap until end the loop, if stop the loop before to ended them are release as well, the problem is when the loop run them are not release and still in the heap after download and storage, what i can see in instrument is that **CFData (store)** is grow up every time and will be release when the loop is ended.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the statement

```
_urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] ;
```

will return an "autoreleased" object.

This has the following consequences:

Since you don't use an autorelease pool in the inner loop, you effectively "hold" all returned data objects in an autorelease pool which is drained somewhere *outside* the inner loop.

In order to alleviate the issue, simple place an autorelease pool within the loop so that the returned object from `dataWithContentsOfURL:` gets released while leaving the inner loop's autorelease pool's scope:

```
for (...) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        ...
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        ...
    }
}
```

---

While using an autorelease pool might help against this issue, honestly, you should also review and reimplement your current method. For example, the way you use dispatch_sync() makes no sense.

You could also greatly improve your code if you would use `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous convenient method - or even better use the delegate approach. (I'm saying this, despite the fact that I know that asynchronously firing up a list of asynchronous tasks isn't that easy, unless you have a good amount of experience with asynchronous patterns.)

Comment: thanks for the info with autoreleasepool I solve some problem but now the problem is that the CFData and no the CFData (store) is growing up, you tell me to use a NSUrlConnection's asynchronous, but what i need is stop this serial queue and with asynchronous i can't, also i need to run this queue in a background queue for work with the app like a normal state, for example i have in another controller some come that have to download other image at same time but this staff have more priority then background download

Comment: I don't think the growth of CFData and CFData (Store) has anything to do with using an autorelease pool. You might investigate this issue with Instruments. But your code suffers from other issues as well. Especially, with the current design you should not expect that it can solve your task properly. You need to approach the problem from a different perspective: use asynchronous programming patterns.